# Batch Variable In Tasklist Issue

Tags: batch-file

So I currently have a simple backup script which only runs if a game server executable is currently running. I am using a variable at the top for the executable name to check for, but for some reason it is not working.

```
set SERVER_EXECUTABLE_NAME="DayZServer_x64.exe"
set SERVER_BACKUP_DIRECTORY=""
set BACKUP_DIRECTORY=""

echo Checking if server is running...

tasklist /FI "IMAGENAME eq %SERVER_EXECUTABLE_NAME%" /FI "STATUS eq RUNNING" | find /I "%SERVER_EXECUTABLE_NAME%" > nul && ( 
    echo Backing up files...
    robocopy "%SERVER_BACKUP_DIRECTORY%" "%BACKUP_DIRECTORY%\%date:/=-% %time::=-%" /mir /s /w:0 /r:1
) || (
    echo Server is not running, skipping backup...
)
```

The following code does not work. For some reason it displays the following error:
**File not found - DAYZSERVER_x64.EXE**

Am I doing something wrong? If I remove the variables in the tasklist call and place the executable name straight in there, it works fine.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This was caused by a simple code error with the initial `SET` command. The way you have it formatted is incorrect for your purposes.

As it stands, `set SERVER_EXECUTABLE_NAME="DayZServer_x64.exe"` is causing `SERVER_EXECUTABLE_NAME` to equal `"DayZServer_x64.exe"` - this will cause `IMAGENAME eq %SERVER_EXECUTABLE_NAME%` to be `IMAGENAME eq "%SERVER_EXECUTABLE_NAME%"`, whitch is fine, *BUT* Your FIND function is already being quoted causing it to look like `""%SERVER_EXECUTABLE_NAME%""` But in the CMD it's `DayZServer_x64.exe` NOT `"DayZServer_x64.exe"`.

In the end I believe what you was meaning to do was the proper way:

```
set "SERVER_EXECUTABLE_NAME=DayZServer_x64.exe"
```

**FixedBatch:**

```
set "SERVER_EXECUTABLE_NAME=DayZServer_x64.exe"
set "SERVER_BACKUP_DIRECTORY="
set "BACKUP_DIRECTORY="

echo Checking if server is running...

tasklist /FI "IMAGENAME eq %SERVER_EXECUTABLE_NAME%" /FI "STATUS eq RUNNING" | find /I "%SERVER_EXECUTABLE_NAME%" > nul && ( 
    echo Backing up files...
    robocopy "%SERVER_BACKUP_DIRECTORY%" "%BACKUP_DIRECTORY%\%date:/=-% %time::=-%" /mir /s /w:0 /r:1
) || (
    echo Server is not running, skipping backup...
)
```